# White Spaces can't store in a variable

Tags: uima, ruta

I'm try to set feature in replace(-(Hyphen)). But it could not be set as feature value in replace.

```
DECLARE RE_HyphenSpace(STRING replace);
DECLARE Replace_HyphenSpace;
RETAINTYPE(SPACE);
SPACE @NEWHYPHEN SPACE{->        MARK(RE_HyphenSpace,1,3),MARK(Replace_HyphenSpace,2,2)};
RETAINTYPE;


BLOCK(foreach) RE_HyphenSpace{}
{
STRING hyphenrepl;
Replace_HyphenSpace{->MATCHEDTEXT(hyphenrepl)};
RE_HyphenSpace{->RE_HyphenSpace.replace=hyphenrepl};
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The block is not executed because RE_HyphenSpace annotations are not visible because SPACE annotations are invisible again after the RETAINTYPE. You need to remove or move the `RETAINTYPE;` line, e.g., to the end of the block.

*DISCLAIMER: I am a developer of UIMA Ruta*